# Image not displaying after being passed as prop to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display an image i am passing to a prop but getting the error

**Cannot find module '../images/blah-blah.jpg'**

Tried looking about online but can't figure out what i am doing wrong. New to react, so sorry if this is really simple.

```
<ProfileCard 
   image='../images/blah-blah.jpg' 
   name='Name' 
   title='(CEO)'/>
```

```
import React from "react"
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

function ProfileCard({image, name, title}) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={require(image)} /> 
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        {title}
      </Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
  )
};

export default ProfileCard;
```

Folder structure

[image]

Comment: The error is telling you that it can't find that file at that path relative to that component.  Did you intend to import the file as a module, or just set its relative URL path as a string?

Comment: On <ProfileCard> change the  to src={image}, currently you have this: src={require(image)} which does not look right

Comment: The path from the ProfileCard component is the same as where its being passed from so should be ok - passing from About.js to ProfileCard.js - updated my question with the folder structure.

Yeah i tried changing it to src={image} but this doesnt display them - no error atleast tho!

Comment: Use this on ProfileCard: <Card.Img variant="top" src={require(image).default} />

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately

Comment: update the question with full code of `ProfileCard.js` top to bottom

Comment: Can you tell the following values **in the browser**: What is the (wrong IIUC) URL set in the resulting HTML `img` tag? What is the URL of the javascript bundle serving React app? What is the URL of the image when you load it manually in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the image like this in the parent component like this

```
import ImageFile from '../images/blah-blah.jpg' 

<ProfileCard 
   image={ImageFile}
   name='Name' 
   title='(CEO)'
/>
```

and then you can use it this way in your ProfileCard component

```
import React from "react"
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

function ProfileCard({image, name, title}) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} /> 
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        {title}
      </Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
  )
};

export default ProfileCard;
```

The require is not necessary, and you can rename `ImageFile` to whatever you want.

Also, make sure the path is right. You can look at a working sample on this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-shtern-qx23ev?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I'm learning react where from `Card.Body` came? i know there are classes in bootstrap `card` but i could not see any component that is defining or setting up card

Comment: card is imported from bootstrap at the top

```import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';```
Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, `react-bootstrap` has this component defined in it? `Card.Body` is not a valid html and i can't see Card component in your example so that means its defined inside the bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, it is defined inside bootstrap, it's called composition in react. You can read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html